# Which machine learning model is applicable to the following case

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I want to build a model that recognizes the species based on multiple indicators. The problem is, neural networks (usually) receive vectors, and my indicators are not always easily expressed in numbers. For example, one of the indicators is not only whether species performs some actions (that would be, say, '0' or '1', or anything in between, if the essence of action permits that), but sometimes, in which order are those actions performed. I want the system to be able to decide and classify species based on these indicators. There are not may classes but rather many indicators.
The amount of training data is not an issue, I can get as much as I want.
What machine learning techniques should I consider? Maybe some special kind of neural network would do? Or maybe something completely different.

Comment: You may want to have a look at kernels and MKL

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: Sadly, not for now, sorry. I'll try when I have more time

Comment: is that it? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_kernel_learning

Comment: If you can normalize input to some form of vector - any classification machine (bayes/NN/kernels/svm something I forgot?) will do pretty fine.

Comment: So you're saying that if I want to differentiate the order of actions, A and B, I can simply express it in numbers? Say, (A->B) = 1 and (B->A) = 0 ?

Comment: This question is not directly related to programming, but to pure Machine Learning. Please consider moving it to stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

If you treat a sequence of actions as a string, then using features like "an action A was performed" is akin to [unigram model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram). If you want to account for order of actions, you should add bigrams, trigrams, etc.

That will blow up your feature space, though. For example, if you have `M` possible actions, then there are `M (M-1) / 2` bigrams. In general, there are `O(Mk)` k-grams. This leads to the following issues:

- The more features you have — the harder it is to apply some methods. For example, many models suffer from [curse of dimensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality)
- The more features you have — the more data you need to capture meaningful relations.

This is just one possible approach to your problem. There may be others. For example, if you know that there's some set of parameters ϴ, that governs action-generating process in a known (at least approximately) way, you can build a separate model to infer these first, and then use ϴ as features.

The process of coming up with sensible numerical representation of your data is called [feature engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_engineering). Once you've done that, you can use any Machine Learning algorithm at your disposal.